# Default attributing routing not working

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, attributerouting

I am working on a new project and i have decided to use attribute routing alone. This is my RouteConfig file:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();

        //routes.MapRoute(
        //    name: "Default",
        //    url: "{controller}/{action}",
        //    defaults: new { controller = "HomeController", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        //);
    }
```

This is my controller:

```
[RoutePrefix("home")]
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    [Route]
    [Route("~/")]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var status = HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated;
        ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";

        return View();
    }

    [Route("test")]
    public ActionResult Test()
    {

        return View();
    }
}
```

I've realised that typically all my attributes are working but i want the Index method to run on application start. Say https://example.com and then the Index method is fired as if i entered the url https://example.com/home/index. I get a blank space when i do say https://example.com.

Can anyone please help me understand why i get a blank space and also how to set the default application start route using attribute routing? I've been surfing the internet for hours but i can't lay my hands on anything.

Comment: Why do you have 2 routes on your index?

Comment: I initially thought that [Route("~/")] will mean an entry point to the application. Should i remove my routes on the index method?

Comment: the tilde (~) overrides the route prefix of the controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
[RoutePrefix("home")]
public class HomeController : Controller 
{
    [Route("index")]
    [Route("~/", Name = "default")]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ...
    }

    ...
}
```

Comment: Can you add the RouteConfig.cs to your answer for me?

Comment: @Willie, you can keep your route config as is.

Comment: Tried but i get blank space. What is the meaning of the blank space i'm getting

Comment: What URL are you getting a blank page? Are you getting a Http 200? If so, then your webserver is returning a blank page (which may mean your View is empty).

Comment: I get 401 unauthorized response

Comment: Then the error is not in the routing, It is in authorisation. If you have `[Authorize]` on your controllers or actions, try removing it temporarily to check your routing. Or you need to login to your app to satisfy the `[Authorize]` requirement.

Comment: Sorry mate, can't do a chat right now. Please try my suggestion above.

Comment: I tried @FrankFajardo suggestion and it also worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

In your case you should still set a default route. That way the site knows where to start. From there everything else should work as you intended.

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes) {
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{action}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" }
    );
}
```

Here is my Home Controller.

```
public class HomeController : FrontOfficeControllerBase {
    public HomeController() {
    }

    public ActionResult Index() {
        ...
        return View();
    }
}
```

Other than that this keeps my route config clean as I use attribute routing everywhere else.

Comment: I receive an exception saying i can't start a route with "/". How do i fix that? The exception was caught on the url: "/" part

Comment: I removed it yet i got a blank page. Should i maintain attribute on the Index action method. Or since I'm using the convention-based routing, i should get that route off?

Comment: Can you please post both your RouteConfig.cs file and your controller for the hello world test you did so i can compare?